# How to share PDF or Text with specific apps using UIActivityViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, uiactivityviewcontroller, file-sharing

I am making an application that will share the barcode (in text or PDF, which work) with banking applications so that the user can make the payment.

How was these pictures, I want that when you tap the button to pay, appear as options in uiactivityviewcontroller, banking applications in question. But I have no idea how to make them appear as an option. I've tried several different ways.

Can anyone give me an idea?

[image: Touching in share but]
[image: Banking applications options]

Ps: The second and fourth options, are both banking applications. How can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: An app appears as an option when the app is registered to work with whatever data is being shared. If an app wants to share a PDF, for example, any app you have installed that specifies it can open PDF files will appear in the list. BTW - please see https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT200289 to learn how to take screenshots.

Comment: But the problem I'm having is that I try to share a PDF with these applications that have appeared in the photos, but none appears. So here I am in the community asking. And about learning how to take pictures, thank you for the link, but these pictures are from a video taken from the Internet.